# Is $f^3r^4fr^2frf$ equal to $e$ or not in $\operatorname{Sym}(P_3)$?

Tags: symmetry, group-presentation

$\operatorname{Sym}(P_3) = \bigl\langle r, f \mid r^3 = e = f^2, fr = r^{-1}f \bigr\rangle$.
As $r^3 = e, r^{-1}  = r^2$ hence $fr = r^2f$.

Relation 1: $fr = r^2f$, Relation 2: $fr = r^{-1}f$

Is $f^3r^4fr^2frf$ equal to $e$ or not?

Using Relation 1, I get $f^3r^4fr^2frf = r$.

Using Relation 2, I get $f^3r^4fr^2frf = e$.

This obviously can't be true, so where am I going wrong?

Comment: It would be easier to see where things might be wrong if you gave your workings.

Comment: Sure, I'll edit them in now.

Comment: Nevermind, I've spotted where I've gone wrong!